# Cannot resolve symbol 'SCOPE_FILE'

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-android-api

I'm new to app development, and I'm working with Android Studio 3.1.4. I'm working with the Google APIs for sign-in, which have worked well when getting the user's ID, email address, and basic profile. However, I'm now trying to get the Google Drive API working, and I've been stuck for almost two days on this one nagging problem, which is the first step in getting this API to work. Here is the code that's being problematic.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .build();
```

For some reason, SCOPE_FILE is showing up red and I get a tool tip that reads, "Cannot resolve symbol 'SCOPE_FILE'" when I hover over it. Based on everything that I've read, this should not be an issue. I've tried restarting Android Studio and my computer several times. I upgraded to the most recent version of Android Studio and the most recent version of Gradle. I'm pretty sure I've imported all the necessary classes, which are listed here:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
```

I feel as though this must be a simple issue with a simple solution, but I can't figure it out. What am I missing?

Comment: you are importing the wrong class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are importing the wrong [`Drive`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.html) class, which does not have the [`SCOPE_FILE`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Drive#SCOPE_FILE) field. The solution is to

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
```

instead of

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
```

Comment: After reading through these docs, I see the difference now, but is there some dependency that I should be including within the project? When I try to import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive, it now cannot resolve 'drive'. 'drive' also is not an option when attempting to autocomplete.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Under Project Structure > Dependencies tab, I added com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1. Once Gradle resynced, all those unresolved symbols are gone. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

import this [See](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Drive)

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
```